# as3, string to variable

Tags: string, actionscript-3

I have array with variable names:

```
var subjectArray:Array=["subject0","subject1","subject2"];
```

I need to convert string to var, but following does not work: `this[subjectArray[0]]` throws an error.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: if the variable is not defined and you still want to dynamicaly add a variable set your class as dynamic (public dynamic class) but if you know the variables names it's better to declare them before. Using dynamic class cause loose of performance.

Comment: I am trying to multiple buttons with same actions...               for(var i:Number=0; i< subjectArray.length ;i++){
 
content.this[subjectArray[i]].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,subjectOver);

 function subjectOver(evt:MouseEvent):void
 {
 content.this[subjectArray[i]].gotoAndStop("hot");

 }


}

Comment: actually I can now see the issue is beyond syntax, as i've been trying to attach the listeners to physically created instances

Answer (score 0):

That syntax should work. You can check if an object contains a property with a given name with the `in` keyword. The property does probably not exist.

```
if (subjectArray[0] in this) {
  // do something with this[subjectArray[0]];
}
```